# Message icon says I have messages to read but I do not. How do I delete the shown numbers?

Tags: ios

How do I delete a text message that is not there for me to delete?  The number still shows that I have messages but I do not.

Comment: Did you try scrolling the whole list of messages?

Comment: Have you tried doing an hard reset?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I have done both to no avail.

Comment: I have had the same problem previously and would be confident that it is a bug of sorts. If you don't mind losing all of the messages in there, I'd recommend deleting the account and then reactivating it.

Comment: Check they're not in the Trash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Persistent badge on Messages app icon - macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/327907/persistent-badge-on-messages-app-icon-macos)

Answer (score 1):

Try signing out of the iCloud account you use for iMessage and sign back in. Settings -> iCloud -> Sign Out. See if that helps.